# Excel Run Time Error

Tags: excel, checkbox, return

"Run-Time error'3'
Return without GoSub"

Above is the error code that I am presented with when I attempt to run my program in excel.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    If Range("G1").Value = "hot" Then
        Call hotjuly17_macro
    ElseIf Range("G1").Value = "cold" Then
        Call coldjuly17_macro
    Else
        Return
    End If
End Sub
```

I choose the Debug option and am presented with "Return" highlighted as the error. What I am trying to do is add another checkbox that hides/unhides the rows I've selected in excel. I've already got it working with one checkbox on this spreadsheet, but this second checkbox is not working for some reason. The code is almost identical with the exception of what rows get hidden/unhidden and where values are placed. (for example, values hot and cold are in G1 for this checkbox that I'm trying to fix, but for the working checkbox the values are in E1. Just thought I'd mention that)

I don't understand what the problem could be, I will be happy to post any code should anyone need to see it.

Comment: `Return` is not a thing in VBA.  That last clause in your `If` isn't required - it's basically a "do nothing" `Else` (or it would be if Return wasn't causing it to error)

Comment: What should it look like then? (I removed the return, but which "If" are you referring to?) Could you type it out please?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    If Range("G1").Value = "hot" Then
        Call hotjuly17_macro
    ElseIf Range("G1").Value = "cold" Then
        Call coldjuly17_macro
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It might be appropriate to add a brief explanation of why this code will work better.